# Scrolling ListBox with buttons WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, listbox

How can i scroll by sections using buttons in WPF?

I have the next ListBox:

[image]

I need each arrow (buttons) from left & right to perform the scroll action (back & next)

Here is my code of the ListBox (since the code of the buttons are not so important i am just pasting the ListBox code)

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="CategoriesListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#00FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#00FFFFFF"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="{Binding ElementName=DummyGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=DummyGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" Margin="2">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontFamily="/BundyPOS;component/Fonts/#HelveticaRounded" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="7" Text="{Binding a}"></TextBlock>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </Button.Content>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding color}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                    <Border CornerRadius="15" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3cb878"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I cant perform `ListBox.ScrollIntoView(categoryItem[position]);` because the ListBox could have different row or values per row. Is there any function like "scrollToHorizontalOffset"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..It is a referance

Create a Window in wpf like this...

```
<Window x:Class="AutoScrollListBox.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AutoScrollListBox"
Title="AutoScrollListBox" Height="600" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AutoScrollListBoxDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="EquipmentItemBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF223B84" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF4B94EC" Offset="0.7"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="EquipmentItemSelectedBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF1C9B37" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF26DE2C" Offset="0.7"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EquipmentItem}" >
            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Width="84" Height="68"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" 
                    Background="{StaticResource EquipmentItemBackground}">
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" TextAlignment="Left" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CampaignName}" 
                               Foreground="White"
                               FontSize="12"
                               TextAlignment="Left" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True" >
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource EquipmentItemSelectedBackground}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl Margin="0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <TabItem Header="Horizontal ListBox" >
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox x:Name="horizontalListBox"  SelectionMode="Extended"
                    Style="{ StaticResource ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Horizontal }"
                    Selector.SelectionChanged="horizontalListBox_SelectionChanged">
                </ListBox>
                <ListBox x:Name="horizontalSelectedItemsListBox" Height="100"
                    Style="{StaticResource ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Horizontal}"
                    >
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="Vertical ListBox" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                <ListBox x:Name="verticalListBox"  SelectionMode="Extended"
                    Style="{StaticResource ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Vertical}"
                    Selector.SelectionChanged="verticalListBox_SelectionChanged">
                </ListBox>
                <ListBox x:Name="verticalSelectedItemsListBox" Width="100"
                    Style="{StaticResource ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Vertical}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItem}"
                    >
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Look the cs code of above window

```
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

 namespace AutoScrollListBox
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem> m_selectedEquipmentHorizontal = new ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem>();
    ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem> m_selectedEquipmentVertical = new ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem>();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnInitialized( EventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnInitialized( e );

        ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem> equipmentList1 = new ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem>();
        this.horizontalListBox.ItemsSource = equipmentList1;
        CreateEquipments( equipmentList1, "Tank-" );
        this.horizontalSelectedItemsListBox.ItemsSource = m_selectedEquipmentHorizontal;

        ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem> equipmentList2 = new ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem>();
        this.verticalListBox.ItemsSource = equipmentList2;
        CreateEquipments( equipmentList2, "Tank-" );
        this.verticalSelectedItemsListBox.ItemsSource = m_selectedEquipmentVertical;
    }


    private ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem> CreateEquipments( ObservableCollection<EquipmentItem> equipmentList, string prefix )
    {
        int maxItemCount = 20;
        for( int i = 0; i < maxItemCount; i++ )
        {
            equipmentList.Add( new EquipmentItem() { Name = prefix + i.ToString(), CampaignName = "Batch_ " + i.ToString() } );
        }
        return equipmentList;
    }



    private void horizontalListBox_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.AddedItems.Count > 0 )
        {
            foreach( EquipmentItem item in e.AddedItems )
            {
                m_selectedEquipmentHorizontal.Add( item );
            }
        }

        if( e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 )
        {
            foreach( EquipmentItem item in e.RemovedItems )
            {
                m_selectedEquipmentHorizontal.Remove( item );
            }
        }
    }

    private void verticalListBox_SelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.AddedItems.Count > 0 )
        {
            foreach( EquipmentItem item in e.AddedItems )
            {
                m_selectedEquipmentVertical.Add( item );
            }
        }

        if( e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 )
        {
            foreach( EquipmentItem item in e.RemovedItems )
            {
                m_selectedEquipmentVertical.Remove( item );
            }
        }
    }

    }
  }
```

Then Create a ResourceDirectory for change style of Window, like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<!-- Fill Brushes -->

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#FFCCCCCC"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" Color="#FFEEEEEE"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

<!-- Border Brushes -->

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>


<Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2"  Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" >
                    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Gray"
                            Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            Opacity="{Binding Path=Opacity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CustomListBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border  Name="Border" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<!--listBoxWithAutoScroll_Horizontal-->
<Style x:Key="ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Horizontal" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value >
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid >
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" >
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                           Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                                           Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                                           Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                           Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Panel}">
                                        <ScrollBar.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand"
                                                                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand"
                                                                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" 
                                                                     Background="Gray" Opacity="0.8" Margin="0,-1" />
                                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                                </Track>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ScrollBar.Template>
                                    </ScrollBar>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter Margin="0,2" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid x:Name="Panel" Margin="0,2" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineLeftButton" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                                  Content="M 8 0 L 8 32 L 0 16 Z"       
                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"       
                                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"
                                  ClickMode="Hover" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineRightButton" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                                  Content="M 0 0 L 8 16 L 0 32 Z" 
                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"       
                                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"
                                  ClickMode="Hover"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility" SourceName="scrollviewer" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="LineLeftButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="LineRightButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineLeftButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineRightButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineLeftButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineRightButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<!--listBoxWithAutoScroll_Vertical-->
<Style x:Key="ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Vertical" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomListBoxItem}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value >
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid >
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" >
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Orientation="Vertical" 
                                                           Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                                           Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                                           Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                           Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Panel}">
                                        <ScrollBar.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                                                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                        <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                                                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                                        <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" 
                                                                     Background="Gray" Opacity="0.8" Margin="-1,0" />
                                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                                </Track>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ScrollBar.Template>
                                    </ScrollBar>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter Margin="2,0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid x:Name="Panel" Margin="2,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineUpButton" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                                  Content="M 0 8 L 32 8 L 16 0 Z"      
                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"       
                                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"
                                  ClickMode="Hover" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="LineDownButton" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                                  Content="M 0 0 L 16 8 L 32 0 Z" 
                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"       
                                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"
                                  ClickMode="Hover"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" SourceName="scrollviewer" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="LineUpButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter TargetName="LineDownButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineUpButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineDownButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineUpButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineDownButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can add items into the ListBox using Binding.So, create a class for it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace AutoScrollListBox
    {
        public class EquipmentItem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string CampaignName { get; set; }
            public string ImagePath { get; set; }
         }
     }
```